# How to specify height for each row in different sections in a UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITableViewController with different sections and rows that I create them programmatically , I want to have specific hight for each sections

would you please let me know how can I put specific hight for each row of sections?

Thanks in advance!

As you can see since I used heightForRowAtIndexPath: I have the same hight for each rows in my sections but I want to have specific hight for each sections

![enter image description here][2]

I know that we have **heightForHeaderInSection** and **heightForFooterInSection** but how I can put specific hight for several section in one table

Here is the code:

**Edit:**

If I use this code then I have big space between my section but I want to have specific hight for each row in different sections

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return 40;
        break;
    case 1:
        return 40;
        break;
    case 2:
        return 80;
        break;
    default:
        return 40;
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To return a different height for different cases according to the section

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            return your_req_height;
            break;            
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

`NSIndexPath` provides both the row and the section so you can return a different height for each row in a section.

It should be added that this method seems fragile, because you are going to tie a specific section/row pair to a fixed height. You should setup your table items with a tag indicating the type of contents in each section/row pair.

Comment: it just added space between my sections I want to hav ehight for each row in diffrent section

Comment: did u mean u want different row heights for different sections but same height of rows in same section?

Comment: @Florent if you check my code "else {
    CheckBoxCompensationViewCell " I have custome cell how can I fix a size for that cell?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code. This will return custom height for your CheckBoxCompensationViewCell type cells. just replace your_required_height with the height of your CheckBoxCompensationViewCell. I have tried 60.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

switch (indexPath.section) {

//Since you have custom cells i-e CheckBoxCompensationViewCell type cells in this section, you need to return custom cell height in tableview
case 2:
    return 60; //i am supposing your_required_height is 60
    //return your_required_height; //height of CheckBoxCompensationViewCell
    break;

default:
    return 44; //default_height of tableview cell
    break;
    }
}
```